# Forecasting ARIMA with `predict` vs `forecast` in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

Data consisting of 30 values is stored in a time series `time`.
After applying ARIMA modelling on `time`, I used `forecast` function to predict future values:

```
model = arima(time, order = c(3,2,1))
prediction = forecast.Arima(model,h=10)
prediction step is not working and showing error 
Error in ts(x) : object is not a matrix
```

As you see above, I am getting an error message. But if I do

```
model = arima(time[1:25], order = c(3,2,1))
prediction = forecast.Arima(model,h=10)
```

it works. Why is it so?

When I used the `predict` function

```
model = arima(time, order = c(3,2,1))
prediction=predict(model,n.ahead=10)
```

it also works.

**Which** function would be better to use, `predict` or `forecast`, for ARIMA models in R, and **why**?

Comment: Always mention the language you use. It's not yet true that the whole statistical world uses R.

Answer (score 8):

They will give you the same answers. But the combination of `Arima` (not `arima`) and `forecast` from the forecast package are enhanced versions with additional functionality.

`Arima` calls `stats::arima` for the estimation, but stores more information in the returned object. It also allows some additional model functionality such as including a drift term in a model with a unit root.

`forecast` calls `stats::predict` to generate the forecasts. It will automatically handle the drift term from `Arima`. It returns a forecast object (rather than a simple list) which is useful for plotting, displaying, summarizing and analysing the results.